# Ошибка "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" при переходе на другой viewController по нажатию кнопки - swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

Ошибка `"Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"` при переходе ко второму viewController (класс "Type1ViewController"), перепробовал все не могу пофиксить, вот код из ViewController.swift и скрин Main.storyboard:[image: Main.storyboard]
Классы view-шек проверил совпадают.
Ошибка также возникает при отсутствии всех TextField-ов на втором экране.
Ошибка отображается вот здесь в AppDelegate:[image: Часть AppDelegate]

```
import UIKit

var position: Int = 1
var positionSecondBack: Int = 0
var answer: String = ""

//=======================================================================
//------------------------ first view controller ------------------------
//=======================================================================
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelTypeEc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelType: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Next1Butt: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var ProblemTypePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PickerAP: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PickerDP: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PickerV: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ProblemTypePicker.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        PickerAP.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        PickerDP.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        PickerV.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        LabelTypeEc.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        LabelType.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        Button1.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        Button2.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        Button3.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        Next1Butt.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        Button1.setTitle(" Вопросы ", for: .normal)
        Button2.setTitle(" Вопросы ", for: .normal)
        Button3.setTitle(" Вопросы ", for: .normal)
        ProblemTypePicker.delegate = self
        ProblemTypePicker.dataSource = self
        PickerAP.delegate = self
        PickerAP.dataSource = self
        PickerDP.delegate = self
        PickerDP.dataSource = self
        PickerV.delegate = self
        PickerV.dataSource = self
    }

    var list1 = ["аннуитентные платежи", "дифференцированые платежи", "вклады"]
    var list2 = ["1-ый тип", "2-ый тип", "3-ый тип"]
    var list3 = ["4-ый тип", "5-ый тип", "6-ый тип"]
    var list4 = ["7-ый тип", "8-ый тип", "-"]

    //how much stacks in pickerView
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var countrows : Int = list1.count
        if pickerView == ProblemTypePicker { countrows = self.list2.count }
        return countrows
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == ProblemTypePicker {
            let titleRow = list1[row]
            return titleRow
        } else if pickerView == PickerAP {
            let titleRow = list2[row]
            return titleRow
        } else if pickerView == PickerDP {
            let titleRow = list3[row]
            return titleRow
        } else if pickerView == PickerV {
            let titleRow = list4[row]
            return titleRow
        }
        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == ProblemTypePicker {
            //buttons witch allow us go to "Type docs"
            //and
            //PickerViews what contain from "1 Type" to "9 Type"
            if row == 0 {
                position = 1
                PickerAP.isHidden = false
                PickerDP.isHidden = true
                PickerV.isHidden = true
                Button1.isHidden = false
                Button2.isHidden = true
                Button3.isHidden = true
            } else if row == 1 {
                position = 4
                PickerAP.isHidden = true
                PickerDP.isHidden = false
                PickerV.isHidden = true
                Button2.isHidden = false
                Button1.isHidden = true
                Button3.isHidden = true
            } else if row == 2 {
                position = 7
                PickerAP.isHidden = true
                PickerDP.isHidden = true
                PickerV.isHidden = false
                Button3.isHidden = false
                Button2.isHidden = true
                Button1.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        //what type of problem
        if pickerView == PickerAP {
            if row == 0 { position = 1
            } else if row == 1 { position = 2
            } else if row == 2 { position = 3
            }
        }
        if pickerView == PickerDP {
            if row == 0 { position = 4
            } else if row == 1 { position = 5
            } else if row == 2 { position = 6
            }
        }
        if pickerView == PickerV {
            if row == 0 { position = 7
            } else if row == 1 || row == 2 { position = 8
            }
        }
        if position == 1 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = false
        } else if position == 2 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = true
        } else if position == 3 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = true
        } else if position == 4 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = true
        } else if position == 5 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = true
        } else if position == 6 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = true
        } else if position == 7 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = true
        } else if position == 8 {
            Next1Butt.isHidden = true
        } else if position == 9 {

        }
    }
}


//=======================================================================
//---------------------- 1 Type1ViewController 1 ------------------------
//=======================================================================
class Type1ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ButtonBack: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ButtonNext: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Lanel4: UILabel!
    //textFields
    @IBOutlet weak var TextField_1Type_1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TextField_2Type_1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TextField_3Type_1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TextField_4Type_1: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ButtonBack.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        ButtonNext.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }
}
```

Comment: Извините если не соблюдаю каких-то норм кода, я начинающий программист.

Comment: Решил проблему пересозданием 2-ого view

Answer (score 0):

у меня был подобная ошибка хоть и все было настроено верно. 
обнаружил что на втором view Controller при нажатии на нем cntrl была подключена дополнительная "розетка". как только я ее удалил - проблема исчезла.

Проверьте что у Вас так же